# Include Predicate Expression filter to include phonetically similar characters in search results

Tags: ios, nspredicate, string-search, nsexpression

How to achieve filtered results that handles phonetically similar character in the search results?

In attached screenshots from `iOS 11 -> Settings -> Region & Languague`: Searching for regions with K also includes Comoros.

I'm experimenting with Predicates/Expressions:

```
    // Name field matching.
    NSExpression *lhs = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"title"];
    NSExpression *rhs = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:searchString];
    NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSComparisonPredicate
                                   predicateWithLeftExpression:lhs
                                   rightExpression:rhs
                                   modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                   type:NSContainsPredicateOperatorType
                                   options:NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption];
    [searchItemsPredicate addObject:finalPredicate];
```

Related Source: [Apple Search Table Sample - APLMainTableViewController.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html)

[image: Search Regions with M]
[image: Search Regions with K]

Comment: What app is the screen shot from?

Comment: Updated screenshot source app: `iOS 11 --> Settings --> Region & Languague`

Comment: Should I add other keywords to improve this question surfacing up on search? This seems like many devs would need to solve.